# PHP: Cannot use [] for reading - but it's not [] but [$counter]

Tags: php, arrays

in general I think I understand what the error message means. But in my case, it's a riddle I didn't succeed in solving...

```
    $keywords_all = array();
    $count = 0;

    for ($z = 0; $z < $num_results; $z++)
    {
        $keywords_array = explode(",", $row['free_keywords']);

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($keywords_array); $i++)
        {
            if (in_array(strtolower(trim($keywords_array[$i])), $keywords_all))
            {
                $count++;
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<br />".$keywords_array[$i];
                $keywords_all[$count] = $keywords_array[$i];
            }
        }

        $row = pg_fetch_array($result);
    }
```

So, what's wrong with that one? The error message pops up in the line

```
    $keywords_all[$count] = $keywords_array[$i];
```

I have no clue, seems to be alright to me. But guess, it's again a tiny, tiny thing I've neglected... Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Split the line into two; use a temporary variable; so you can determine if the error originates right or left hand side. Also try `${'keywords_all'}[$count]` etc. while you're at it (though `[]` operator precedence is only a problem for object props mostly).

Comment: I can't reproduce this error; can you give us test values for `$row['free_keywords']` and `$keywords_all`?

Comment: I split it into two lines, and it comes from "$keywords_all[$count] = $temp;". And the one in brackets {} doesn't work either. Values are just some words like "Agriculture","cereals","production","Population","female".

Comment: `foreach()` might make for neater code than those `for()` loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce your error message. I did find a bug in your code though (I am assuming that you are putting all your keywords in the $keywords_all array without any duplicates). So you should not increment $count inside your IF but instead update the $keywords_all count. See below:

```
if (in_array(strtolower(trim($keywords_array[$i])), $keywords_all)) {
    $count = count($keywords_all);
} else {
    echo "<br />".$keywords_array[$i];
    $keywords_all[$count] = $keywords_array[$i];
    $count++;
}
```

You will increment $count after storing a value to your $keywords_all array.

Comment: Thanks for that. I though I'd copy that one line where I get the error message from your code, you never know... And it worked. He?!?! Now, I have two lines which are the same, but where the first generates "$keywords_all[$count] = $keywords_array[$i];" the error message and the second one not: "$keywords_all[$count] = $keywords_array[$i];". Mystery!!

Answer (score 0):

```
    $keywords_all = array();
    $count = 0; // what for you neet this var ?

    $myRow = 'keyW1,keyW2,keyW3,keyW2';

//    for ($z = 0; $z < $num_results; $z++) // there is no variable $num_results at your code so I've replaced it with constant
    for ($z = 0; $z < 1; $z++)
    {
//        $keywords_array = explode(",", $row['free_keywords']); 
        $keywords_array = explode(",", $myRow);

//        for ($i = 0; $i < count($keywords_array); $i++)
        foreach ($keywords_array as $keyword)
        {

            $keyword = strtolower( trim( $keyword ) ); // some syntax sugar would be nice

            if ( !in_array( $keyword, $keywords_all) )
            {
                echo "<br />".$keyword;

                $keywords_all[] = $keyword;

            }
        }

//        $row = pg_fetch_array($result);
    }

    var_dump($keywords_all);
```

This code would be better for you i think, but if you just want to get rid of duplicated records

```
array_uniq( array("1", "1", "2", "1") )
```

would be better solution for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tweaking. Looks much nicer!